# How to pass parameter into autofac using RegisterType and Controller factory

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, autofac

I have this class:

```
public class MessageService
{
    private readonly IMessageSender messageSender;

    public MessageService(IMessageSender messageSender)
    {
        this.messageSender = messageSender;
    }
}
```

How to register autofac to pass parameter inside constructor:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
var container = builder.Build();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
builder.RegisterType<MandrillMessageSender>().As<IMessageSender>();

builder.RegisterType<MessageService>(new MandrillMessageSender()); // NOTE THIS STRING IS NOT WORKING
```

So the result should work like this, when I pass parameter inside controller constructor messageService object should be created with inserted MandrillMessageSerder.

```
public Home(MessageService messageService)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do all the `RegisterType` calls before calling the  `builder.Build()`

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
builder.RegisterType<MandrillMessageSender>().As<IMessageSender>();
builder.RegisterType<MessageService>();

var container = builder.Build();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

Note that you don't need to pass anything in the `MessageService` registration if you have only one implementation of the `IMessageSender` interface (Autofac will figure it out that you need the `MandrillMessageSender` there)

Comment: Thank you friend! Just tried it and it works perfectly! In fact I made stupid mistake with registration order. Before I didn't use autofact so that's why was confused! Thank you a lot again :)